# How to detect Collision within a tablelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a tableLayout that is created programmatically, about 23 items are added to the table. if i click an item I want to move that item to a next available on the table closer to the item. Can someone tell how I can implement this.

For instance, a board like [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/photo-slide-puzzle-android-app/) with one free cell. How do you make sure the item move to the right space.

Thanks

Comment: can you give more explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dealing with a users input you can set setOnItemClickListener for your tableLayout. This will trigger a function like the one below when the user clicks within the table.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long id)
```

You can then retrieve the contents of the cell using the View parameter, or the Int pos parameter if you have a container storing your items in the same order.